# Pthreads and Structures C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, structure

I am using structures in C++, and i try to save pointers in that structures, but when i try to use that structure in a thread i cant get the data of the structure.

```
struct threadData {
   void* memPointer;
   void* instructionPointer;
   void* stackPointer;
   int memsize;
};

void *worker_thread(void *arg) {
    struct threadData *my_data;
    my_data = (struct threadData *) arg;
    cout<<"INSTRUCTION POINTER: "<<my_data->instructionPointer<<endl;
    cout<<"MEMORY POINTER: "<<my_data->memPointer<<endl;
    cout<<"STACK POINTER: "<<my_data->stackPointer<<endl;
    cout<<"MEMORY SIZE: "<<my_data->memsize<<endl;

 }

 int main() {
    pthread_t my_thread;
    int ret;
    struct threadData td = { calloc(1, 32), calloc(1000000, 64),     calloc(34, 4),6475 };
    ret = pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, worker_thread, (void *) &td);
    pthread_detach(my_thread);
    //pthread_exit(NULL);
 }
```

But when i use pthread_exit(NULL) after pthread_detach i can use the information of the structure in the method "worker_thread".

Comment: If you're using C++, why aren't you using a constructor to initialize your struct? You're also using C-style casts, and using the `struct` keyword to refer to your struct type (which is almost never necessary in C++). This is very C-like C++ code...

Comment: C++11 implementation of what you're trying to do: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0b3dadb23bd7bba

Comment: @kfsone You might yet replace calloc calls with `new char[x*y]` to get it entirely C++-like. Just for completeness, I would yet free/delete the allocated data. Sure, it is not necessary here, but consequently thinking ahead of destroying any allocated memory right from the start might prevent you from creating memory leaks some time in the future...

Comment: In addition to Aconcagua's suggestions, I would move the `new` calls for the fields *inside* the constructor, and the constructor would just take the sizes as arguments. The `void*` types also irk me... There's almost always a better alternative to `void*` in a well-designed C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

Since `td` is allocated on the stack in `main`, it gets clobbered by some clean-up code that the runtime executes after you return from `main`. Allocate your `td` struct on the heap instead of on the stack, and it will work as expected:

```
struct threadData tdVal = { calloc(1, 32), calloc(1000000, 64),     calloc(34, 4),6475 };
struct threadData *td = malloc(sizeof(*td));
*td = tdVal;
// ...
ret = pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, worker_thread, (void *) td);
```

However, you still have a problem. [Returning from main will kill the other pthreads in your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305478). Since there's no synchronization in your code preventing `main` from completing before `worker_thread` is run, you can't even guarantee that `worker_thread` will run at all.

You should probably *not* detach the worker thread, and instead use `pthread_join` to make sure it has completed before returning from `main`. Also note that if you ensure `main` does not return before `worker_thread` completes, then there's no problem with leaving `td` on the stack.

Comment: If using pthread_join, no problem with having td on the stack, though.

Comment: @Aconcagua - Yes, thanks. I've updated the answer to make that point clear.

Answer (score 2):

Without `pthread_exit`, you are returning from `main`, and the local variable `td` is destroyed before the other threads are completed.

By calling `pthread_exit`, you force the main thread to wait for the other threads to complete, so `td` doesn't get destroyed too early.

As @Aconcagua noticed, the documentation for `pthread_exit` says that the calling thread is terminated.  It doesn't make an exception for the main thread, so at least in principle, the main thread's stack could disappear while the other threads were still executing.  This means that even with the call to `pthread_exit`, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: From [pthread_exit man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html): "The value pointed to by retval should not be located on the calling thread's stack, since the contents of that stack are undefined after the thread terminates." If this applies for the main thread, too, the same applies for td - and you result in undefined behaviour when accessing td within the other thread.

Comment: @Aconcagua: I'm not sure what point you are trying to make, since `retval` (the argument to pthread_exit) would be NULL in this case.

Comment: Important point is not retval, but that the stack gets undefined - and so `td` in our case. So if accessing `td` from the other thread, it is undefined behaviour (unless pthread_exit behaved differently if called from the main thread - no hints in the link I provided, though).

Comment: @Aconcagua.  Yes, I see. I was thinking that the stack on the main thread would be preserved until all the other threads completed, but it looks like that isn't guaranteed.